# How to fix 'Internal Server Error' for Zend Server?

Tags: zend-framework

I just downloaded ZendServer 6.2.0 and installed it to my computer. My OS is Windows 7. When I tried to launch the desktop icon, the browser said 'Internal Server Error'. How should I go about checking the root cause and fix it? How can I start using the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working. I am posting the solution here in the hope that it will help others.

I checked "Zend Server/Apache2/logs/error.log" and found that a line says: "Zend Enabler cannot load because of a problem in its configuration file: XML parse error on line 1 column 1 - invalid byte '?' at position 3 of a 3-byte sequence"

Here is the solution:
Open "Zend Server/Zend Server/etc/ZendEnablerConf.xml". You will see some messed up characters in the first line. Delete them. Make sure the first line is properly tagged. Restart the Apache2.2 Zend Server at your system tray.

Now you can launch the icon.